# Android studio plain java library proguard

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, android-library

Is it possible to have different build types for plain java libraries in Android Studio with gradle? My intention is to run proguard and minify the jar file size.

**Java build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**Android build.gradle**

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "test.app"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
}
productFlavors {
    buildWithSingleAlarmFlavour {
        applicationId "test.app"
        versionName ".1"
    }

    buildWithMultipleAlarmFlavour {
        applicationId "test.app"
        versionName "0.1"
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?